# Adding Multiple Views to a VC++ 2010 SDI using MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, sdi, cview

I'm trying to add multiple (actually 3 ) views to an SDI application and give the user choose witch View will be load according to his choice :

[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Nmp.png)

I have followed this tutorial in the official MS documentation . 
So, have created three classes :  CAdminView CAssistantView CBiblioView and an authentication class associated to a dialog frame .

My Questions are :

1) how to edit this three view classes (Graphically) ?

2) at first time I want to show just the authentication dialog window , how to do that ?

```
* I tried to change m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

  by m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE); but no expected result
```

3) I expect to load the view according to parameter,  this is what I added to the InitInstance funnction  :

```
                CView* pActiveView = ((CFrameWnd*) m_pMainWnd)->GetActiveView();
                m_BiblioView = (CView*) new CBiblioView;
                m_AdminView = (CView*) new CAdminView;
                m_AssistantView = (CView*) new CAssistantView;
                CDocument* pCurrentDoc = ((CFrameWnd*)m_pMainWnd)->GetActiveDocument();

                // Initialize a CCreateContext to point to the active document.
                // With this context, the new view is added to the document
                // when the view is created in CView::OnCreate().
                CCreateContext newContext;
                newContext.m_pNewViewClass = NULL;
                newContext.m_pNewDocTemplate = NULL;
                newContext.m_pLastView = NULL;
                newContext.m_pCurrentFrame = NULL;
                newContext.m_pCurrentDoc = pCurrentDoc;

                // The ID of the initial active view is AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST.
                // Incrementing this value by one for additional views works
                // in the standard document/view case but the technique cannot
                // be extended for the CSplitterWnd case.
                UINT viewID = AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST + 1;
                CRect rect(0, 0, 0, 0); // Gets resized later.

                // Create the new view. In this example, the view persists for
                // the life of the application. The application automatically
                // deletes the view when the application is closed.
                m_AdminView->Create(NULL, "Fenetre Administrarteur", WS_CHILD, rect, m_pMainWnd, viewID, &newContext);
                m_AssistantView->Create(NULL, "Fenetre Assistant", WS_CHILD, rect, m_pMainWnd, viewID, &newContext);
                m_BiblioView->Create(NULL, "Fenetre Bibliothecaire ", WS_CHILD, rect, m_pMainWnd, viewID, &newContext);
                // When a document template creates a view, the WM_INITIALUPDATE
                // message is sent automatically. However, this code must
                // explicitly send the message, as follows.
                m_AdminView->SendMessage(WM_INITIALUPDATE, 0, 0);
                m_AssistantView->SendMessage(WM_INITIALUPDATE, 0, 0);
                m_BiblioView->SendMessage(WM_INITIALUPDATE, 0, 0);
```

and this is my switch function :

```
CView* CMiniProjetApp::SwitchView(int Code ) //1 : Admi / 2 : Biblio / 3 : Assistant
{
   CView* pActiveView =((CFrameWnd*) m_pMainWnd)->GetActiveView();

   CView* pNewView= NULL;
   switch(Code){

   case 1 : pNewView= m_AdminView; break;
   case 2 : pNewView= m_BiblioView; break;
   case 3 : pNewView= m_AssistantView; break;
   }

   // Exchange view window IDs so RecalcLayout() works.
   #ifndef _WIN32
   UINT temp = ::GetWindowWord(pActiveView->m_hWnd, GWW_ID);
   ::SetWindowWord(pActiveView->m_hWnd, GWW_ID, ::GetWindowWord(pNewView->m_hWnd, GWW_ID));
   ::SetWindowWord(pNewView->m_hWnd, GWW_ID, temp);
   #else
   UINT temp = ::GetWindowLong(pActiveView->m_hWnd, GWL_ID);
   ::SetWindowLong(pActiveView->m_hWnd, GWL_ID, ::GetWindowLong(pNewView->m_hWnd, GWL_ID));
   ::SetWindowLong(pNewView->m_hWnd, GWL_ID, temp);
   #endif

   pActiveView->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
   pNewView->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
   ((CFrameWnd*) m_pMainWnd)->SetActiveView(pNewView);
   ((CFrameWnd*) m_pMainWnd)->RecalcLayout();
   pNewView->Invalidate();
   return pActiveView;
}
```

Any errors notices ??!!

*please help me !

Thanks .

Comment: Kudos for writing 16-bit Windows compatible code!

Answer (score 0):

Showing and Hiding the window is the correct way. But you Need to set the view as active too. 
You find the required working codein this MSDN Sample [VSSWAP32](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141334).

The required code to switch  and hide the other views is shown in the article.